# IoT Hub Equivalent For IoT Central Offline commands

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, offline-mode, azure-iot-central

What is the IoT Hub Equivalent For IoT Central Offline commands?
[See Documentation For Offline Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-use-commands#offline-commands)

Does
"storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
"timeToLiveSecs": xxxxx sec} Time to live could be applied for the same ?

I hit a wall. Please help.

Comment: IoT Central   Offline allows sending instructions to devices even when they're disconnected.

Comment: Exactly, What is the IoT Hub Equivalent ?

Comment: Yes, the timeToLiveSecs property in the storeAndForwardConfiguration setting for IoT Hub messages can be used to define the message expiration time. Azure IoT Central offers a comprehensive set of features for managing IoT devices, including device provisioning, device management, data collection, data visualization, and analytics. refer to this so for the difference between Azure IoT [hub](https://spyro-soft.com/blog/cloud/iot-hub-vs-iot-central) and Iot [Central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425557/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-iot-hub-and-azure-iot-central)

Comment: Have a look at the Cloud-To-Device Messages in the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d

Comment: Choose an Internet of Things (IoT) solution in [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/iot/iot-central-iot-hub-cheat-sheet) and Extended offline operation with Azure IoT [Edge](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extended-offline-operation-with-azure-iot-edge/)

Comment: Azure IoT Edge supports extended offline operations on your IoT Edge devices and enables offline operations on downstream devices too in the Azure IOT hub. Stores any messages that would go upstream and saves them until the device reconnects.
Acts on behalf of IoT Hub to authenticate modules and downstream devices so they can continue to operate.Enables communication between downstream devices that normally would go through IoT Hub. So In Azure IoT Hub, the equivalent functionality to IoT Central's offline commands can be achieved.